# Not able to affix the sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my website: http://readerproject.comuv.com/

I am looking for a way to affix the sidebar. I did this:

```
$("#sidebar").affix({
  offset: { top: 0 }
});;
```

But this is not working. The sidebar is not fixing at it's position. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

P.S: I am building the website using Bootstrap.

Comment: Do you know how to open the JS error console? "affix" doesn't exist. Did you forget to include a jQuery plugin/bootstrap core files?

Comment: @RwwL Ofcourse I know about the console. No error. I have included all the files.

Comment: OK, the error I was seeing was actually about "freetile": "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - readerproject.comuv.com/js/scripts.js:4" appears in the console for me when I hit the URL you provided. "freetile" isn't defined and is breaking execution after that. But I don't see a call to affix in scripts.js, so you're right, this appears to be a separate problem. Where are you calling affix?

Comment: Weird that there's no error message, but it kind of looks like bootstrap isn't executing at all: running $.fn.affix from the console on yoru page returns undefined, whereas the function definition is returned if you run the same command on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: (Aside: sorry about the console question if you were insulted; I didn't look at your reputation number, and a lot of people honestly just need to be shown where that is. I didn't mean it snarkily.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like count.php is adding another version of jQuery to the page, wiping out all your plugins.

[image]

Comment: :O How could I block that file?

Comment: Oh, is your host including that file without your knowledge/consent? Yuck. I'm not sure if you could block it, but you can use jQuery's noConflict feature to make sure your scripts and plugins are kept together under a new global variable and don't get wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

put your jquery js file link on top of the bootstrap files as given below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></scri
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and just resolved by placing inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sidebar").affix({
    offset: { top: 0 }
  });
});
```